# DLL injection prior to process execution

Tags: c++, directx, hook, dll-injection

I am trying to use dll injection to intercept a call to `Direct3DCreate8` from my application to acquire a handle to the Direct3d device and draw an overlay on the screen that it projects. The call to this API happens right after the application's execution which, if I understand correctly, renders useless the **dll injection into running process** technique as the API call I was after has already happened when I inject the dll. 
Is this assumption correct? If yes, how can one inject the dll during process execution to catch a desired API call?

**EDIT:** I am aware of system-wide api hooks but would be nice to hear a 'local' solution to this problem.

**EDIT 2:** Forgot to mention, replacing the .dll in the application's folder is of no use, as the application looks for the .dll (d3d8.dll in my case) in System32/SysWOW64 directories.

Comment: (Not a full answer, so I'm posting it as a comment) Have a look at the debugger API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809754.aspx - processes started for debugging will start suspended, so you can inject your DLL, then unsuspend it , then stop debugging it. (Even though your program isn't actually a debugger, it can use the debugger API)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being a bit late for the party I wanted to offer you a solution of using [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) (which is free for non-commercial use on x86 platforms and costs tremendous money otherwise). They have a `DetourCreateProcessWithDllEx` function that might suit your needs.

Quoting Detours documentation:

> The process is created in a suspended state with the CREATE_SUSPENDED flag to CreateProcess. Detours then modifies the image of the application binary in the new process to include the specified DLL as its first import. Execution in the process is then resumed. When execution resumes, the Windows process loader will first load the target DLL and then any other DLLs in the application's import table, before calling the application entry point.

Comment: I ended up using detours when I was developing this project :) Thank you

Comment: Detours is now open source and completely free for both x86 and 64-bit